# SAPUI5 SplitApp Master and Detail Page not working

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am trying to create a Detail-Master page using OData service in SAPUI5. Everything works fine in the Master page.

When I clicked on the item on the Master page, it brings down to the Detail page, but I could not get the data in the Detail page.

I have put the alert function to debug in the Detail page. This code will never be executed.

```
var oList = new sap.m.List({headerText: "Material Details", items:
        [

            new sap.m.DisplayListItem({label:"Material:",value:"{Material}"}),
            new sap.m.DisplayListItem({label:"Material:",value:{
                path:"Materials",
                formatter:function(iValue){ 
                    alert('Here!!');
                    var test = this.getBindingContext();  
                    console.log('SS:' + test);

                    var currentdate = new Date(); 
                    var datetime = "Last Sync: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                                    + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                                    + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
                                    + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                                    + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                                    + currentdate.getSeconds();

                    return currentdate + " sq km";
                }
            }})
         ]});
```

Any idea why? do we need to get the model ?

Herer is the full source code:

https://github.com/ferrygun/SAPUI5

Comment: Your full source code is quite complex for someone to be able to quickly understand what's going on and help you. I'd suggest you distill the problem down to the smallest possible example and edit your question accordingly.